# Creating multiple blocks programmatically

Tags: 7, blocks

I am writing a custom module for Drupal 7. I need to create 5 different blocks with the module. Drupal has the `hook_block_info` and `hook_block_view` hooks which create blocks. How can I add multiple blocks since these hooks allow only one block per module?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following code should help.  You'll obviously need to add your 5 blocks as appropriate, but it's just to show how you can add multiple blocks in one module:

```
function MYMODULE_block_info() {
 $blocks = array();
 $blocks['myfirstblock'] = array(
   'info' => t('My block admin info'),
   'status' => 1,
 );
 $blocks['mysecondblock'] = array(
   'info' => t('My second block admin info'),
   'status' => 1,
 );

 return $blocks;
}

function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'myfirstblock':
      $block = array(
        'subject' => t('My first block title'),
        'content' => t('My first block content'),
      );
      break;
    case 'mysecondblock':
      $block = array(
        'subject' => t('My second block title'),
        'content' => t('My second block content'),
      );
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}
```

Reason for `status => 1` from [`hook_block_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) API docs:

> status: (optional) Initial value for block enabled status. (1 =
>   enabled, 0 = disabled). Most modules do not provide an initial value,
>   and any value provided can be modified by a user on the block
>   configuration screen.

I'm not sure where you got the one block per module idea from.  You can create as many blocks as you'd like in a module.